# Как сделать более приоритетной одну версию компилятора над другой в linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

У меня установлено 2 версии компилятора, gсс-9 и gcc-10, при использовании по умолчанию выбирается gcc9. Как мне сделать более приоритетным gcc10?

Comment: Кем именно по-умолчанию? `/usr/bin/gcc` - это символьная ссылка на конкретную версию, которую можно изменить.

Comment: через update-alternatives чтоб не сломалось при обновлении

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7834049/8086115) @jopasserat.*

---

Как уже предложил @Tommy, вы должны использовать `update-alternatives`.
Он присваивает значения каждому программному обеспечению семейства, так что он определяет порядок, в котором будут вызываться приложения.

Он используется для поддержания различных версий одного и того же программного обеспечения в системе. В вашем случае вы сможете использовать несколько склонений `gcc`, и один будет предпочтительным.

Чтобы выяснить текущие приоритеты gcc, введите команду, указанную в комментарии @tripleee's:

```
update-alternatives --query gcc
```

Теперь обратите внимание на приоритет, приписываемый `gcc-4.4`, потому что вам нужно будет дать более высокий приоритет `gcc-3.3`.
Чтобы установить свои альтернативы, вы должны иметь что-то вроде этого (предполагая, что ваша установка `gcc` расположена на `/usr/bin/gcc-3.3`, а приоритет `gcc-4.4` меньше 50) :

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-3.3 50
```

--upd--

Наконец, вы также можете использовать интерактивный интерфейс `update-alternatives` для легкого переключения между версиями. Введите `update-alternatives --config gcc`, чтобы вам было предложено выбрать версию `gcc`, которую вы хотите использовать среди установленных.

-- upd 2 --

Теперь, чтобы исправить переменную окружения `CXX` в масштабах всей системы, вам нужно поместить строку, обозначенную @DipSwitch's, в ваш файл `.bashrc` (это будет применяться только к вашему пользователю, что, на мой взгляд, безопаснее):

```
echo 'export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc-3.3' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Лучше дать ссылку на [оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu), чем текст автоперевода.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть компилятор по умолчанию будет называться просто *gcc*. Тогда:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s gcc10 gcc
```

Теперь, если в ваших Makefile-ах встретится *gcc*, то будет вызван gcc10.